# iOS7 PJSIP Audio Issues 3G

Tags: ios7, 3g, pjsip, stun

I am facing audio issues while trying to use PjSip in an iOS app.

Issue 1. If I enable STUN I see that audio works perfectly over WiFi, but on a 3G network there is absolutely no audio.

Issue 2. If I disable STUN, it works over WiFi. But on 3G I only receive audio during outgoing calls but on an incoming call there is absolutely no audio.

I have tried disabling VAD as suggested in http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Audio_Problems/Getting_Around_Nat, but no improvements
I am using the latest build of pjsip created out of the trunk. And my code is more or less based on the siphon app.

Any help in this regard will be much appreciated.